# Move arrayed object towards centre

Tags: animation

I'm trying to create an abstract visualiser wherein 7 blocks move towards the centre of a circle. I'm really struggling to find a way to create straight line movement from individual blocks towards the centre.

Here's what the scene looks like so far. I made a simple rectangle and used an array modifier to clone it 7 times in a circular shape.

[image: Arranged blocks]

I'm trying to animate each block moving towards the centre of the circle at different times and different amounts. Problem is, I've got no way of creating a straight transform keyframe animation aimed exactly at the centre. Preferably, I'd have all the blocks moving like this (to varying degrees).

[image]

I've tried some stuff with the local axis but all the blocks have homogenous global and local properties when the array is applied and the blocks separated by selection.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

i have no idea about your knowledge of geometry nodes, but i think it is a pretty nice example for the use (or a reason to learn) of geometry nodes.

With this node setup

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

Comment: heh nice result :). still looks like magic to my brain :D

Comment: thanks so much!!

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with geometry nodes. I'm trying to recreate your node setup but I don't know what the equal node is. Also, I've got some questions about customising the setup to my specific needs. Will the geometry nodes allow me to move each block inwards a set amount and will I be able to change them with the graph editor? I'm way more familiar with keyframes.

Comment: @Confused_User: maybe you should invest some time learning it ;) one good learning source is in my opinion Erindale (yt) who explains a lot while doing it. CGMatter makes also good geometry nodes tutorials. The equal node is just the compare node set to equal. Of course you can change the amount by changing the map range node. And of course you can "normal" keyframe (nearly) all values of the nodes and edit them in graph editor.